# useSearchParams 'react-router-dom' changes url pathname too

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my custom hook to control search parameters. But when I call `deleteSearchParams`, it works but it also changes the pathname to `'/'`.

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';

function useSearchParameters(queryKey?: string) {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const queryParams = useMemo(() => {
    return queryKey ? searchParams.getAll(queryKey) : [];
  }, [searchParams, queryKey]);

  const appendSearchParams = useCallback(
    (param: { [key: string]: string }, replace = false) => {
      setSearchParams(param, {
        replace,
      });
    },
    [setSearchParams],
  );

  const deleteSearchParams = useCallback(
    (queryKey: string) => {
      searchParams.delete(queryKey);
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    },
    [searchParams, setSearchParams],
  );

  return {
    searchParams,
    queryParams,
    appendSearchParams,
    deleteSearchParams,
  };
}

export default useSearchParameters;
```

As far as I know, `useSearchPrams` hook from 'react-router-dom' only controls search params, not pathnames. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You are correct, the `setSearchParams` function works like `navigate` but ***only*** for the queryString. Think you could create  *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese created codesandbox test link -> https://codesandbox.io/live/a5bd6cec4c8
It works here..!! But just does not on my project.

Comment: The issue doesn't reproduce for me in that sandbox. Clicking "add param" navigates to `"/other-page?param=hello"` and clicking "delete param" navigates back to `"/other-page"`. What is different between your actual code and the codesandbox? Are all the same package dependencies on the same/correct versions?

Comment: @DrewReese It has the same version of 'react-router-dom' but different 'react' and 'react-dom' versions. I just found out that 'deleteSearchParams' function move the location back to the page where it's **refreshed/loaded**. When the page is loaded with the pathname '/other-page', it returns to '/other-page' after deleting the param.

Comment: Can you create another sandbox with correct matching package versions and exact reproduction steps to follow?

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry, the custom hook wasn't a problem..! I found the issue from a click event I was applying the hook..! Thanks for your help.